# Wicket Complex Data class for models

Tags: java, wicket

I'm a starter in using Wicket, and I think I just managed to understand how models work, which is great, but there is a hole in my understanding:

When working with Models for a custom, complex type, let's say `Person`, then I'll create a `PersonData` class with the proper fields and getters/setters, then create a `PersonModel`, which implements the model for this `PersonData` class, so naturally, I'll have a field with the type `PersonData`.

Now the question:

When implementing the `setObject(Person newObject)` method for the Model, is it prefered to copy over the fields of the parameter object, like `this.object.setFirstname(newObject.getFirstname())`, or can I just copy over the parameter instance, like `this.object = newObject;`?

With the latter, I of course copy the reference of this instance, so if I set some other model this instance and do some changes to that, then all the other models will change as well, which might be undesirable, that's why the question arose.

What is the better practice in this case?

Comment: Not really an answer to your queston but: I don't see the need for creating a special PersonModel. If you already have a simple java bean class PersonData you can just use PropertyModels or a `CompoundPropertyModel<PersonData>` to work on that class.

Comment: Not full answer too :) setObject in few type of applications (reading etc) is not used , i'm not fluent in english, but can say 'second category' to implement (some 'fabric' implementations are empty). If implemented, I believe new reference is better

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to create a PersonData class, it is sufficient to use the IModel interface with generics:

```
 IModel<Person> personModel = Model.of(person);
```

which will return a typed instance of a model.
Your model then does not hold a copy of the original object but a reference of the original person object itself, which is also the recommended way of using models in wicket.

This model can then be used in all components. It is also recommended to use PropertyModels or CompoundPropertyModels for accessing individial fields of a model object. This avoids creating Models for every component individually.

Comment: Just make sure Person is `Serializable` in the approach. Else use a `LoadableDetachableModel`